# Как сделать законченный ряд новостей?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

Есть два типа блоков как показано на картинке ниже, один по ширине равен двум маленьким.

Проблема с их построением решилась js скриптом (собственно для этого и делалась тогда эта картинка) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на картинке как видно нижний ряд заканчивается полностью закрыв ряд.
Но если к примеру выводить 9 новостей и в них будут к примеру 3 широких блока, тогда 3 новости вываливаются на новую строку, так как широкий блок занимает 2 обычные, получается что 3 широких, вымещают 3 новости.

Я никак не могу написать такую выборку что бы он выводил только 9 новостей которые бы заканчивались законченным рядом.

Объясните может я что-то не там уже ищу? Как вы это делаете разработчики?
Я уже не раз приводил в пример [этот сайт](http://www.the-village.ru).
Так как в нем реализовано 1 в 1 то что мне нужно.

Как они получают законченный ряд имея два типа блоков?

Вообще вопрос про rails, так как именно там я пытаюсь это реализовать, и именно в контроллере я пытаюсь сделать эту выборку.
Но так как не имею понятия как это реализовывают, решил спросить в других категория.

Comment: нужно чтобы между двумя "большими" новостями было четное число "маленьких".

Comment: а если использовать такие ресурсы http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы понимаете под между "большими" ведь у сайта примера, могут идти подряд к примеру 3 большие, а может между двумя большими быть всего одна.

Comment: Masonry это вообще не-то, так как проблема сортировки блоков не стоит. Вся проблема именно в том как вывести только нужное количество новостей, в случае если есть 1 или более "больших"

Comment: а высота блоков тоже разная? или одинаковая?

Comment: Одинаковая, но вы наверное смотрите на картинку, проблема с сортировкой уже решена, задача про дургое